# Problem with accessing jasperserver behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location, jasperserver

i have several instances of dockerized jasperserver instances. They are running on the same server on different port.
On the same server i also has a nginx server running too.

i have following settings on Dockerfile to host `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/` instead of `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/jasperserver`.

Dockerfile

```
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
RUN mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
RUN rm -r /usr/local/tomcat/work
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>ROOT.root</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My environments are as follows.

[image]

So when i point to `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:13429/`, i can login to jasperserver with credentiuals.

My next step is to access jasperver via nginx.

This is my location block for ops env.

```
location /reporting-ops/ {

        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        rewrite ^\/reporting-ops\/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:13429/$1;
}
```

when i type `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/reporting-ops/` on the browser i get redirected. (Please see image)

i have done same kind of url rewriting for other applications and they work fine. So i assume this must be something to
do with jasperserver.
[image]

Thank you Very much.

[image]

########
Further findings.

when I type http://xx.xx.xx.xx/reporting-ops/login.html I can see the login page without .css & .js loading. When I look at the request initiator chain I see below. The first request has /reporting-ops/ but in the subsequent requests http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/reporting-ops/... is missing. But when if we check URL http://xx.xx.xx.xx/reporting-ops/runtime/5CD5658f/themes/reset.css the .css file is available.

My nginx block look like this now.

```
location ~ ^/reporting-ops {

              proxy_set_header    Host $host;
              proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   8083;
              proxy_redirect ~^/reporting-ops/(.*)$ http://192.168.125:13429/$1;

}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the `Location` header value you get on the first request from the screenshot? I wrote I comment under one of your previous questions, you did not read it, did not understand the given part of the answer I'm referring to or simply prefer not to respond? You'd need a `proxy_redirect` directive to solve this, and you cannot use it with your current configuration.

Comment: @IvanShatsky modified the question with an image for the Request headers. The blurred out ip address is the ip address of nginx, not the jasper container or it's host.